# Numbers Between Formula

Tags: numbers, iwork

```
IF(AND(B13≤74,B13≥75,B13>90),"0","3, 5")
```

I'm trying to generate an *if statement* that outputs either 0 if under 74 or under 3 between 75 - 89 and 5 if over 90. I have been trying the above however I'm getting both 3 and 5 displayed. Could someone help me find the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF(B13>74,IF(AND(B13≥75,B13<90),"3","5"),"0")
```